# how to change scatter symbol url of a Highstock with a function?

Tags: highcharts

I want to give value for plotOptions.scatter.marker.symbol of highstock using some kind of function.This is how i wrote my code, but i dont see the symbol in my graph. Please help me with this.

```
plotOptions={  
scatter:{
  marker:{
     var a;
     a=myFunction();
     symbol:a
        }           
    } 
   }
 };
 function myFunction() {

    if(true){
return 'url(http://www.lib.udel.edu/ud/ill/images/green_marker.gif)';
}
else{
return 'square';
}
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of code needs to be changed:

```
marker:{
     var a;
     a=myFunction();
     symbol:a
```

}

You can define variables inside function only. Not inside Highstock code block.

So, Here I have changed

```
plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 3,
                        symbol:myFunction(),
                    }
                }
            }
```

code to add symbol to Scatter graph.

You didnt mention condition. So, I think you should tailor the example according to your need.

Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/YgxEB/1/